# DatagridView cell editable by mouse wheel

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

What I would like to do is to click on a cell in a datagridview on a windows form and change the content of the cell (a number) up or down depending on the scroll direction and number of rolls of the wheel mouse.

I have no idea where to start I tried looking and I mainly come up with scrolling issues and such which isn't useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on MouseWheel event ..

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_MouseWheel(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseWheel

    DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value + (e.Delta / 120)

End Sub
```